# Multicast destination address and port translation (NAT/PAT)

Tags: multicast

I have a requirement to translate multicast traffic destination address and port number. I see that Cisco has a feature called Multicast service reflection which translates the IP address, but it does not translate/change the port number. Is there any Cisco product or any configuration which can be done Cisco routers to achieve multicast address and port translation?

Alternatively, is it possible with any other vendor Juniper, Fortigate etc?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at recent releases of NXOS for the Nexus 9K the [service reflection](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/dcn/nx-os/nexus9000/102x/configuration/multicast-routing/cisco-nexus-9000-series-nx-os-multicast-routing-configuration-guide-release-102x/m_configuring_pim_9x.html#Cisco_Concept.dita_b5571757-2d3f-49da-833d-ad31642deee7) docs actually show translation of both address and UDP port.

In particular this command-

> [no] ip service-reflect destination in-grp to out-grp mask-len g-mlen
> source in-src to out-src mask-len s-mlen[ to-udp udp-to-src-port
> udp-to-dest-port] [to-udp-src-port udp-to-src-port] [ to-udp-dest-port
> udp-to-dest-port]

Example:

> switch(config-vrf)# ip service-reflect destination 228.1.1.1 to 238.1.1.1
> mask-len 32 source 80.80.80.80 to 90.90.90.90 mask-len 32 to-udp-src-port
> 500 to-udp-dest-port 600`

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. I will test this in the lab and make sure it works!